# How to get physical path of a website/app

Tags: c#, iis, msdeploy

How do I get the physical path of a website (for example "MyWebSite") from C#? My server is IIS 7.

Using msdeploy from c#, I have the following code:

```
var deployBaseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions
{
    ComputerName = connectOption.UrlPublishing,
    UserName = connectOption.UserName,
    Password = connectOption.Password,
    AuthenticationType = "Basic",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

i.e `var path = Server.MapPath("~");`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me.

How do I get the physical path of a website using msdeploy api c#?
[Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd543277%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Has anyone worked with them?

Like this:[Execute MSDeploy from C# program code like an API](http://tech.en.tanaka733.net/entry/msdeploy-from-csharp/)

What if my program will not execute on server. 
I think that `Server.MapPath` does not help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
var path=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath.Tostring();
```

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.100).aspx)